# Faster way to find control in sharepoint pages Edit,New

Tags: sharepoint, jquery-selectors

Can any body give me better way to find control in sharepoint page.I user below code to find control in sharepoint page.
$("nobr:contains('Add Another Contractor')")

May be better or faster way if any Please tell me.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

An alternative:

1. Find the table cells using this selector: `table.ms-formtable td.ms-formlabel`
2. For each cell, get the nobr (maybe use [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/))

I currently work with prototype.js, but you can take a look at the library I maintain: [SPUtility.js](http://sputility.codeplex.com/). You don't mention what you're attempting to do with the elements, but it may help.